# How to change SimpleBar height in component, no style global in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How can I change the height of my scrollbar I have seen that `simplebar-scrollbar :: before` works but only in the global style and that would affect other components, I need to use it only in my component

Comment: Please share your code. SO guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style anything deep inside a component using **::ng-deep**.

Example selector in component style:

```
child-component ::ng-deep grandchild-component
```